# Update user between units

Tags: c#, parse-platform, unity-game-engine

I am using Parse in my new game app, and  facing an issue. My users are registering into my game using ParseUser. This part is going great.

My question is, how do I make sure that when a user uses one device, lets say iPhone, and makes some updates to the user account.Then later he turns on his iPad, logged in to the same user account.Now how do I make sure that the user data is updated before he continues on the iPad.

Hope someone can either point me in the right direction or clarify how to.

Thanks in advance :-)

##### EDIT

OK, I have tried this, but that does not seem to work :-(

```
ParseUser.Query
    .WhereEqualTo("email", user.Get<string>("email"))
        .FirstAsync().ContinueWith(t => {
            ParseUser tempuser = t.Result;

            if(tempuser.UpdatedAt != user.UpdatedAt){
                print ("User is out of sync");
                user = tempuser;
            } else {
                print ("User is in sync");
            }

        });
```

Really hoping to get help on this :-)

Comment: In addition to the code, can you say something about what it does do that you want it not to or doesn't do that you want it to? "It doesn't work" isn't enough info to go on.

Comment: Sorry, it is the user = tempuser. It does not seem to update the user object. It might have something to do with the Parse session. Not sure how to deal with this.